# passing arrays to functions and accesing all the elements

Tags: c

In the below program i have passed the array `a` to `Sum`. I want to ask that passing `a` just a means we are passing the address of the first member in the function. Then how the function accesses the 2 and other elements of the array? Does that loop i have used calls the other members? If not put a loop within the Sum function then would i be left with `Sum` as just the first member of the array `a`? Cause i am not looping through all the values of array in that case?

Other thing is the size of operator i have passed a in that to calculate the size of the array. But when i have a structure say: struct node{...}; why do i need to pass complete name with the word struct i.e. sizeof(struct node) why can't i do like this sizeof(node) like we did in case of arrays?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int Sum(int a[], int size)
{
int i,sum=0;
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
sum+= a[i];
}
return sum;
}


int main()
{
int a[]= {1,2,3,4,5},b;
size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
b=Sum(a);
print("%d",b); 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` is a variable, `struct node` is a type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression

```
a[i]
```

is equivalent to

```
*( a + i )
```

where a is a pointer. So if a points to the first element of an array then `a + 0` also will point to the first element of the array. `a + 1` will point to the second element of the array and so on.

Thus expression `( a + i )` points to i-th element of the array where i is changed from 0 to size - 1.

So it is enough to pass the function a pointer to some element of an array and to specify how many elements are follow including the pointed element.

As for structures and enumerations then in C you have to specify them because their names belong to different namespace than other identifiers including typedef names. If you do not want to sue tag names of structure and enumerations then use typedef declaration. For example

```
typedef struct node node;
```

Comment: I didn't know you could "typedef struct node node;". Am I wrong when I say that in C it could have been like in C++ where you can refer to you struct with its name only ?

Comment: @RealProgrammer57 Yes you was wrong. In C the the same name used with tag struct and used as a variable name are two different names that is they belong to different name spaces. So you can write for example Struct A { int x; }; and int A; in the same declarative region. In C++ this ambuiguity is resolved with the elaborated name. When you need to refer the structure you shall use struct A. For example
struct A { int x; } A; struct A B;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow why we are passing int a[]? How is it pointing to a? I know we can also do int *a which is equivalent to int a[] but how?

Comment: @Noobsplzdon't-1 Using as a function parameter int a[] is adjusted to type int *a So for example these two declarations void f( int a[], int n ); and void f( int *a, int n ); declare the same one function.

Comment: @Noobsplzdon't-1: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 1):

In main, "a" is an array, so all the elements are next to each others in memory (i.e. a[1] follows a[0] in memory, etc.).

in the function Sum, "a" becomes a pointer, but in C you can use the same syntax for arrays and pointers (an array is converted to a pointer when using operator []).

so when you write a[i], you are not calling anything, you are just accessing the memory at offset i from address a.

### edit

About structs, please refer to Vlad answer.

Comment: "*but in C the syntax is the same for arrays and pointers*" -- I wouldn't put it that way. The `[]` indexing operator requires a pointer and an integer as its two arguments. You can write either `array[i]` or `pointer[i]`, not because the same syntax applies to both arrays and pointers, but because an array name is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first argument. There is no `[]` operator for arrays, only for pointers (though, at run time, the pointer must point to an element of an array object).

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes it was not exact. Thank you, I edited my answer.